# Awk - store line that matched range pattern start

Tags: awk

I use awk to operate on lines within a range, but I need to use the line the matched the range pattern start in my action.

Now I am doing this:

```
awk '/BANANA/,/END/ {if ($0 ~ /BANANA/) line=$0; print line, $2}' infile.txt
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? A way that does not require me to store $0 at the beginning of the range? Does awk keep this line somewhere?

Thanks and best regards

EDIT (added samples):

infile.txt

```
few
r t y u i
few
BANANA
    a b c d
    a b c d
    a b c d
    a b c d
    a b c d
    a b c d
    a b c d
END
r t y u i
ewqf
few
r t y u i
few
r t y u i
f
```

expected output

```
BANANA 
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA
```

Comment: Please post some sample data with expected output.

Comment: Providing your solution without sample data and expected output will not help us to help you. Please add sample Input_file and expected sample output in code tags.

Comment: no, there is no special variable, you have to do it yourself... also, as per your code, lines matching start/end regex will also be printed, is that what you need? showing us sample input/output will help

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use a range expression as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then need a complete rewrite when you need to do anything the slightest bit more interesting. Always use a flag instead. Instead of:

```
awk '/BANANA/,/END/ { do something }' infile.txt
```

you should write:

```
awk '/BANANA/{f=1} f{ do something } /END/{f=0} ' infile.txt
```

and then to enhance that to do what you want now is simply:

```
awk '/BANANA/{f=1; line=$0} f{ print line, $2 } /END/{f=0} ' infile.txt
```

and any other changes (e.g. skip first line, skip last line, etc.) are equally trivial.

Comment: This is actually the closest thing to what I wanted, as I wanted to avoid the if statement in my example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only "trick" I can suggest in your case is "assignment in condition":

```
awk '/BANANA/ && (r=$0),/END/{ print r, $2 }' infile.txt
```

- `(r=$0)` - assign current record value (i.e. `BANANA`) to variable `r` **only once**, thereby avoiding condition check `if ($0 ~ /BANANA/)` on each record within a range

---

The output:

```
BANANA 
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA b
BANANA
```